# Controls are not center vertically on Title View of iPhone and those are goes downward and cut from bottom

Tags: iphone, forms, xamarin

if for all controls in Shell.TitleView i have set VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" or "Center" then also controls are not center align

[image]

Controls are not center vertically on Title View and those are goes downward and cut from bottom.

Comment: I found the related issue on the GitHub and you can refer to this link about [Custom Shell.TitleView content not positioned correctly on iOS.](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14558)